# How can I smoothen this Chebyshev type I bandpass filtered signal?

Tags: filter-design, bandpass, chebyshev-filters

I'm unable to figure out the cause behind my noisy bandpass filtered signal, despite my adaptation of the paper's parameters, in which they specified it to be a 4th order Chebyshev type I bandpass filter for the bandwidth of [6 18]Hz. The filter is applied in both forward and reverse directions, which made me opt for Python's `filtfilt` function.

```
f1 = (6/fs)*2
f2 = (18/fs)*2
b, a = cheby1(4, 0.001, [f1, f2], btype='bandpass')     
f_sig = filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=0, padlen=len(data)-1)
```

As you can see I even tried to minimize the maximum ripple allowed by setting it to 1e-3. Hereunder I show my own result, under which is shared also that of the reference.

**Original**

[image]

**Reference**

[image]

#### EDIT

I forgot to mention, the data is an ECG signal taken from Physionet's [MIT/BIH](https://physionet.org/content/mitdb/1.0.0/) dataset, record 205, the segment of which is taken from sample 154800 to sample 158400. The paper in question can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1746809411000292).

Comment: What’s your sample rate ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is? I don’t see what it is…

Comment: @Hilmar All the MIT/BIH records' sample rates are 360Hz, and I double checked it.

Comment: @Jdip The problem is that my filtered signal has ostensibly more noise than what it is supposed to when compared with the reference. The P waves for instance are not smoothed out as in the reference, and the amplitude variation are not as large either. Sorry for the ambiguity but I'm a bit new to this

Comment: Can you include a link to the paper in your question?

Comment: @Jdip I updated it

Comment: I still don't see any "noise", but I assume that's because of the resolution of your image, and that you see it on your end. This looks like a perfectly reasonable ECG to me. I also don't see an amplitude problem... That being said, you might want to try giving a little more room on the ripple (0.01?), your filter will have sharper transition bands.